# Is there a way to plot date ranges (Start Date/End Date) value on Echarts Bar Chart?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I was wondering if this can be done on echarts.

I have categories on the y-axis and date values on the x-axis. The values will be the start date and end date for the category.

This is the chart produced by the code below.
[image]

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'time',
    axisLabel: {
          formatter: function (value, index) {
              var date = new Date (value);
              return date.toLocaleDateString("en-US")
          }
      }
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['Category1', 'Category2', 'Category3', 'Category4', 'Category5', 'Category6'],
    axisLine: { show: true },
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Task 1',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [
          new Date('2022-04-10').getTime(), 
          new Date('2022-04-12').getTime(),
          new Date('2022-04-14').getTime(),
          new Date('2022-04-16').getTime(),
          new Date('2022-04-18').getTime(),
          new Date('2022-04-20').getTime(),
        ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Task 2',
      type: 'bar',
      data: [
        new Date('2022-04-04').getTime(), 
        new Date('2022-04-07').getTime(), 
        new Date('2022-04-08').getTime(),
        new Date('2022-04-03').getTime(),
        new Date('2022-04-09').getTime(),
        new Date('2022-04-12').getTime()]
    }
  ]
```

What I wanted to achieve is something like this.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried replacing **null**  with new date where you dont want the date?

Comment: @MuhammadUsama I'm not sure how to do that. But what I'm thinking is the data that I'd pass to the series would be

 [start date, end date], [start date, end date] 

So that the shaded part would be, let's say from 4/18/2022 to 4/19/2022

Comment: @MuhammadUsama figured out what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got this answer from echarts' dev which is also the same suggestion by @Muhammad.

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/zh/editor.html?c=bar-waterfall